# how do you add data to .json file

Tags: javascript, json, shopify, shopify-app

How would you add data to a .json file that is already on a website? I kinda of get how you add data to a .json locally but if I need to send it to a file that has already been created and hosted.

This is my code so far in my server.js file

```
router.post('/themes', async (ctx) => {



      const results = await fetch(`https://`+ ctx.cookies.get("shopOrigin") + `/admin/themes.json`, {
        headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Access-Token": ctx.cookies.get('accessToken'),
        },
      })
      .then(response => response.json());
      ctx.body = {
        status: 'success',
        data: results
      };
  });
```

and this is the code in my frontend .js file

```
async function getUser() {

        const query = [
            {
              "theme": {
                "name": "Lemongrass",
                "src": "https://codeload.github.com/Shopify/skeleton-theme/zip/master"
                }
            }
        ]

        var url = "/themes";
        var method = 'post';
        fetch(url, { method: method, body: query})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
    };
```

I can pull the data aka the themes on my console, however, I need to send the data so I can create a new theme.

Answer (score 0):

you're not very clear but if I understand you properly you're saying

step 1 - you called an endpoint and got a response as JSON

step 2 - you modified it and you want to send that data to a different endpoint.

assuming I'm correct above, this is the answer

let assume after step 1 the data returned is this

```
let response = [1,2,3,4]
```

and to modified it to

```
let newData = [{value: 1},{value: 2},{value: 3},{value: 2}]
```

then in step - 2 send newData instead of response.

what to take away?

if you make any modifications to a data from an endpoint then it's safer to save your modifications to a new variable in this case newData